# Why file is broken when used AES to decrypt?

Tags: c#, aes

i have encrypt/decrypt code for encryption file.
i used succeed with RijndaelManaged but when changed to used AES decrypted file is broken

code used to decrypt file :

```
        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(skey);
            aes.IV = iv;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            int data;
                            while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                            {
                                fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Setting the key size triggers key generation so that the previously set key is overwritten. Remove the line `aes.KeySize = 256`. If problems persist, post both the working and the failing code.

Comment: Verify below things

Verify the key size: AES has key sizes of 128, 192, or 256 bits. Verify that the key size specified in the code matches the key size used during encryption.

Check the padding mode: AES uses a block size of 128 bits and the default padding mode is PKCS7. If a different padding mode was used during encryption, you will need to specify it in the code.

Verify the IV: The Initialization Vector (IV) is used in conjunction with the key to encrypt the data. Verify that the same IV is used in both the encryption and decryption code.

Comment: @Topaco when remove aes.keysize=256 problem solved but how can set keysize value ?

Comment: The key size is *implicitly* set when the key is set. This can be easily verified by checking the key size (`aes.KeySize`) after setting keys (`aes.Key`) of different sizes (128, 192, 256 bits): The key size corresponds to that of the previously set key.

Comment: @Topaco how can convert any string to keyvalue ?

Comment: A key is derived from an (arbitrarily long) string/passphrase with a key derivation function (KDF) in conjunction with a random salt. The salt is not secret and is needed to reconstruct the key (usually the salt is concatenated with the ciphertext). Examples of KDFs are PBKDF2 or the more modern Argon2.